# Using youtube-dl, how do I get the length of an extremely long playlist

Tags: bash, youtube-dl, playlists

Using `youtube-dl`:s json capabilities together with `jq` like so:

```
youtube-dl -J --flat-playlist [playlist_url] | jq '.entries | length'
```

I can get the number of videos in a playlist. This does consume an unnecessarily large ammount of bandwidth for the data desired but if the number of videos is low that is usually ok. For playlists with a significant number of videos the bandwidth cost becomes unreasonable. Also, the process does take an extremely long time to finish if there are many videos. One playlist I tried did not finish even after an hour, I had to ctrl-C the job.

Hence i wonder the following:

Is there a way to get the number of videos in a playlist that uses a more reasonable amount of bandwith and that will not take such a large amount of time to complete if the playlist contains a significant number of videos?

Comment: What do you mean by length? The number of videos or the duration of all videos?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I updated the question

Comment: Can you if possible provide the link to a playlist that "did not finish even after an hour"?

Comment: Sure! https://www.youtube.com/c/thedavidpakmanshow/videos

Comment: The link leads to videos but not a specific playlist. Which playlist(s) is/are problematic?

Comment: youtube-dl treats the url as a playlist, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: On my side (maybe because I am using Windows), youtube-dl can't download the Json metadata based on that link. It is giving error.